# Connection with business object and class

Tags: java

I have to have an accountlist java that uses array to store a list. this java program needs to have count property, and i just need to make sure the following is right because when I test it it is wrong
here is the actual question

> Part I – Now build an AccountList  Business Class.  This class will have a list of Account Objects.  You can use an Array or an ArrayList to store this list.  I would also have a count property to keep track of how many Accounts are in the list.  Methods should include a display() method, and an add(Account a1) method.
>
> Part II – Now add a new Property to the Customer class.

```
AccountList aList;
```

> Make it so that when an User calls the selectDB(3001) method(and passes a custid), the Customer class will go look in the database for all accounts that belong to this customer and put them in the use the aList object.  So the Customer class will contain a list of Accounts that the customer owns.

```
public class Accountlist {
    private int count = 0;
    private final Account aArray[] = new Account[10];

    public void addAccount(Account a1)
    {
        aArray[count]= a1;
        count++;
    }
    public void display(){
        int i;
        for(i=0; i<count; i++) {   
            aArray[i].display();   
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: *because when I test it it is wrong* How is it wrong? Can you elaborate on any errors?`Accountlist` != `AccountList`. Please check that this was not a simple typo. Also, the instructions say you can use an `ArrayList`. I would prefer that over an array with a hardcoded size.

Comment: What exactly are you testing? Do you have unit tests?

Comment: I dont see the necessity of a count variable

Comment: @J.Lengel - I do.  Look again.

Comment: @cricket_007 im pretty much testing that AcctNo, Cid, Type and balance, all be stored in a list, and some cid have multi accounts ATTACHED TO THEM

Comment: Okay, sure, but do you have Junit code to exercise that behavior?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have the business objects, not sure what a junit is

Comment: JUnit is commonly used to programmatically verify Java code... Anyway, it's not really clear what your issue is for this question. You said something is wrong, but have not clarified that.